# Solving a cubic using triple angle for cos (i.e $\cos(3A)$)

Tags: trigonometry, cubics, roots-of-cubics

a) Show that $x=2\sqrt{2}\cos(A)$ satisfies the cubic equation $x^3 - 6x = -2$ provided that $\cos(3A)$ = $\frac{-1}{2\sqrt{2}}$

I did not have a difficulty with this question, I have provided it for requisite context.

*b) Using the previous result, find the three roots of the equation $$x^3-6x+2=0$$ giving your answer correct to four decimal places.*

I had an issue with this question and would love an explanation as to how to solve it. The answer being kept to four decimal places is also trivial.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @Mikhael: I started with one, you do the others.

Comment: You already know one root. Use long division and then apply the quadratic formula to solve for the other two roots.

Comment: @Clayton I don't understand your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $A=\frac13\arccos\left(-\frac1{2\sqrt2}\right)$. Then $\cos(3A)=-\frac1{2\sqrt2}$, and therefore $2\sqrt2\cos(A)$ is a solution of the given equation. But, by the same reason, so are the numbers $2\sqrt2\cos\left(A+\frac{2\pi}3\right)$ and $2\sqrt2\cos\left(A+\frac{4\pi}3\right)$. So, the three roots that you are after are $2\sqrt2\cos(A)$, $2\sqrt2\cos\left(A+\frac{2\pi}3\right)$ and $2\sqrt2\cos\left(A+\frac{4\pi}3\right)$.